# C# variable in XAML code

Tags: c#, xaml, code-behind

I have a partial class code behind for a XAML form.  Here is the code behind:

```
partial class GalleryDictionary
{
    private void GalleryItemLabelPropertyChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
        if (mainWindow == null)
            return; 

        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb == null)
            return;

        var sip = tb.DataContext as StereoImagePair;
        if (sip == null)
            return;

        sip.Label = tb.Text;

        mainWindow.Db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

That is the entire DOC.XAML.CS file after the namespace declaration.

In my XAML file I need to access a variable from this XAML.CS file that I'd like to call DriveOnRight.  Here is the line I've been fighting:

```
        <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="26" Height="26" IsChecked="True" Click="GalleryItemLabelPropertyChanged" CommandParameter="2" Name="PS" Content="{Binding DriveOnRight}"></ToggleButton>
```

Where the XAML file reads....Content="{Binding DriveOnRight}" is where I need to access the variable from the CS file and display it there.

How do I do that?

Any help sure will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this is in your code behind, to remain consistent with your approach, you could use a dependency property for your value.

```
public string DriveOnRight
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DriveOnRightProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DriveOnRightProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DriveOnRightProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DriveOnRight", typeof(string), typeof(GalleryDictionary));
```

Although I would suggest Krish's design is better with the use of a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the way:

```
public class GalleryDictionaryViewmodel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private string _DriveOnRight;
     public string DriveOnRight
     {
         get{ return _DriveOnRight;}
         set{ _DriveOnRight = value;}
     }
}
```

In your CodeBehind File (DOC.XAML.CS):

```
partial class GalleryDictionary
{
      public GalleryDictionaryViewModel GDViewModel;
      public GalleryDictionary()
      {
          GDViewMOdel = new GDViewModel();
          GDViewModel.DriveOnRight = "";
          this.DataContext = GDViewModel;
      }
}
```

In Your Xaml file:

```
 <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="26" Height="26" IsChecked="True" Click="GalleryItemLabelPropertyChanged" CommandParameter="2" Name="PS" Content="{Binding DriveOnRight}"></ToggleButton>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a value in the code behind that is associated to the LOADED function of the button or toggle button or whatever object uses it.

In a level above your function to set the value, make code like this.

```
    public static string DriveOnRight = "True";  
    //"True" could be a condition or function or whatever.
```

Then, it might look like this in the code behind:

```
    private void DS_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton tg = sender as ToggleButton;
        if (//WhateverYourPathToTheVariable//.DriveOnRight == "True")
        {
            tg.Content = "DS"; 
        }
        else
        {
            tg.Content = "PS";
        }

    }
```

And then...in the XAML code, you have this:

```
        <ToggleButton Loaded="DS_Loaded" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="26" Height="26" Name="DS" Content="DS"></ToggleButton>
```